# LuaLatex + Unicode-math, can't get upright greek with "\up*" commands

Tags: luatex, greek, unicode-math

I was trying to type in upright greek letters in LaTex, and I've been recommended to use LuaLaTex with Unicode-math package to accomplish that.

However I ran into a weird issue. If I want to type in upright letter `$\upmu$`, it will be displayed as italicized. I can only get it by typing  `\mathrm{\mu}`. Below is an example and its output. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
This will not work: $\upmu$ $\mitAlpha$

But this will work: $\mathrm{\mu}$ $\mathit{\Alpha}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want all Greek letters upright as standard or is the focus here only the single case of pi?

Comment: Hi Joseph, only the single case. I looked up the table in unicode-math manual (http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) and it shows that the upright greeks should be produced by "\up*" commands. Just curious why this does not work here.

Comment: I agree the doc does seem to be confusing: I'll report this to Will. [An aside: You can get that file on your system using `texdoc -l unicode-math` or using the generic CTAN linke http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf.]

Comment: @JosephWright: Imho it is not only a documentation problem. Like Manuel I do find it illogical that an `\up..` command ends up italic. There should be a clear distinction between the layer of "fix" commands names that allows one to access a specific symbol (and which should be complete) and the layer of generic commands which are affected by math styles and other options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes I agree, but at the least the docs should make this clear. I've sent Will an e-mail to say it needs addressing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How greek letter are typeset depends on the option `math-style`. With e.g. `french` both `\upmu` and `\mu` will be upright, with `ISO` both are italic.  (I do find this confusing too, that `\upXXX` ends up italic ...). If you want to force upright mode for a single instance use a markup command like `\mathup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math} %or french, TeX, literal, upright

\begin{document}
$\upmu \mu x  $ 
$\mathup{\mu}$ 
$\mathit{\Alpha}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If that's the expected behaviour, I think it's wrong. `\itmu` (or similar) should be italic and `\upmu` should be upright. Now the `math-style` should determine wether `\mu` equals `\upmu` or `\itmu`.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, this reminds me a paragraph in the unicode-math manual that I did not quite understand (5.1 Math ‘style’). I am wondering if `math-style` controls the typeset, then what is the difference between `\mu` and `\upmu` in terms of unicode mapping?

Comment: @Manuel The name of italic variant is `\mitmu` (and like `\upmu` it changes with the math-style). And yes I would have found more logical too if both would not be affected by math-style..

Comment: Might be worth reporting this to Will: it's entirely non-obvious from `unimath-symbols` that `\upmu` only works 'as described` if `math-styl` is set to something other than `TeX`!

Comment: @yuntaoc: `\mu` is defined as `\mitmu`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, sorry I overlooked it. Just to clarify a little, what you mean is that if `math-style` is set to `ISO`, then both `\mitmu` and `\upmu` would be mapped to the same unicode-character (italicized mu). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @yuntaoc `\show\upmu` gives `> \upmu=the letter μ.` while `\show\mitmu` gives `> \mitmu=the character .` in my log, so they are not the same: the outcome depends on the setting for `math-style`.

Comment: @JosephWright I compiled Ulrike's code, when `math-style` is set to `ISO`, `\mu`, `\mitmu`, and `\upmu` all show the italicized mu in the pdf. I am not very familiar with how to check the log so I can not tell on that part.

Comment: @yuntaoc How they come out depends on the processing of those different characters. That's not the same as saying they have the same definition.

Comment: @yuntaoc: Well try it out. But yes unicode-math does a lot of mapping (e.g. a x in your input is mapped to an italic x). The styles affect also chars that you input directly. "" would get upright with french math styles.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks, I think I have a wrong understanding of the typesetting process. I always thought the program determines what character(roman or it) and then use the corresponding unicode to look up a glyph in the font book to put onto the pdf. I think I need to do more studying of typesetting process to better understand your answers. But for the scope of the current issue, I think both you and Ulrike have made it very clear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, that's precisely what I was asking. I typesetted your code and saw the outcome. That made me think that maybe no matter which command I used, down underneath the program was considering them all the same in terms of unicode. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for reopening the discussion. I have read the answer in 2021, but it behaved different  in TeXLive 2020. I ask a new question here, would you mind have a look of it?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583177/i-cant-get-an-upright-greek-letter-with-mup-but-i-can-do-it-with-up-in

Comment: @Syvshc is correct: due to changes in `unicode-math`, your answer is no longer up-to-date and could use a revision.

Comment: @Davislor I have now over 4000 answers on this site. And I'm quite sure that quite a lot are outdated. I sometime update some of them, but in general I prefer that they reflect the state at the time of writing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I’ve submitted another answer below. Not many people are going to scroll down and read it, but I don’t want to edit your answer without your approval.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[math-style=literal,range={"00F0-"03D6}]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
This will work: $\upmu\upalpha x$ $\mitAlpha$

But this will work: $\mathrm{\mu}$ $\mathit{\Alpha}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but literal will affect also normal variables like x, and you would have to type them as `\mitx` etc if you want italic variables.

Comment: Very true but I think entirely non-obvious from reading the docs!

Comment: Sure, but it is no problem to define the literal style only for the greek letters. See edited answer.

Comment: Well that's a good idea.

Comment: @Herbert thanks for the alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to assume the earlier answers were correct when posted, but in 2021, you really want `\symup{\alpha}`, etc.  Using `\mathrm` will get you the font set by `\setmathrm`, which by default does not contain Greek letters.  You can, however, pass `unicode-math` the `mathup=sym` package option to make `\mathup` an alias for `\symup`, and similarly `mathrm=sym`.

As of 2021, `\upmu` should work, and `\mupmu` has the old behavior of being equivalent to typing μ.

Comment: yes the whole set of `\sym...` commands were added in  2015 so Ulrike can be forgiven (although that is optional:-) https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/blob/master/CHANGES.md#v08--20150729--breaking-changes-in-this-update

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I thought it was something like that. Since people are referring to this answer in 2021 and getting confused, it could use an update.