# I can't get an upright greek letter with `\mup**` but I can do it with`\up**` in unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I'll use `\beta` as an example.

First I want to ask that how to use "Macro" column in `texdoc unimath-symbols`? I've seen that the upright beta letter had the macro `\mupbeta`, so I tried to use `\mupbeta` to get the upright beta. However I got a italic one.

Second I didn't see explaination of `\mup**` in `texdoc unicode-math`, but `\up**` in sec 5.1.
[image: \up**]

Third, what is the difference between `\symup{\beta}` and `\upbeta`, and in which situation should I use `\symup{\beta}`, `\upbeta`, `\mupbeta` ?

Fourth I checked if there is another question and found it https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214058/180617. That answer said that with difference `math-style` setting, `\upbeta` and `\itbeta` behave the same, and I have to use `\mupbeta` to get an "always upright beta". However in my test, `\mupbeta` and `\mitbeta` behave the same and I can use `\upbeta` to get the upright beta. Is there anyone could explain this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=french}
% \unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}
\begin{document}
    Here is \verb|math-style=french|
    % Here is \verb|math-style=ISO|
    
    $ \mitbeta, \mupbeta, \symup{\beta}, \upbeta $
\end{document}
```

[image: math-style=french]
[image]

Comment: I believe that, if you want `\mupbeta` and `\mitbeta` to always do what they say, the style you want is `math-style=literal`. I believe `\mupbeta` is treated as if you’d typed in `β`.

Comment: But `\aymup{\beta}` and `\upbeta` do, I believe, always work regardless of the `math-style`.

Comment: Although Ulrike Fischer is a very knowledgeable commenter and her answers are consistently excellent, either the package has changed since she posted that in 2014, or she somehow made a mistake. I presume the former.

Comment: the changelog http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/CHANGES.md shows that in 2015 there were a number of breaking changes: v0.8  (2015/07/29)  *Breaking changes in this update!*. Beside other the sym commands came and commands like \upbeta.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot for the information, would you like to make the comment an answer and I'll give it acceptation. :)